# How to download files from box links (which can have multiple ppt/videos files) and rename that file from Excel column?

Tags: python, box

I have various box links in one of the Excel column. I need to download the files from box folder and rename it.

download from the box link and rename as format.. km_enablement_day_no_file_name(downloaded from box). for e.g. it would be FtmIp_1_abc

[image: download from the box link and rename as format.. km_enablement_day_no_file_name(downloaded from box). for e.g. it would be FtmIp_1_abc]
A python code will be helpful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because your question is not that specific, here is some code that shows the principle of what i think you want to do.

```py
import csv
import requests

with open('data.csv') as csv_file: # open the csv file with your name, day and url
    csv_data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    
    for row in csv_data: # looping through the rows of the csv file
        r = requests.get(row[2]) # get the url from the row in the csv file and make a get request

        # write the content behind the url to a file. You may need to change the file name extension 
        with open(row[0]+row[1]+".unknown", "wb") as file:
            file.write(r.content)
```